# What is a function satisfying these constraints?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I'm looking for a monotonically increasing function $f\colon (0,1)\times(0,1)\mapsto(0,1)$ satisfying:

1. $f(x,y)=1-f(1-y,1-x)$
2. If $x >\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x, y)>y$
3. $f(\frac{1}{2}, y)=y$
4. If $x <\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x, y)<y$

So far, I've figured out that if $x+y=1$, then $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore by monotonicity, $f(x,y)\ge\frac{1}{2}$ in the upper half, and $f(x,y)\le\frac{1}{2}$ in the lower half. 1. and 3. imply that if $y=\frac{1}{2}$, then $f(x,y)=x$. Also, the lower left quadrant is less then $\frac{1}{2}$, and the upper right quadrant is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. I conjecture the function might be symmetric about $x=y$.

$\frac{x+y}{2}$ satisfies 1., but fails 3. because $\frac{\frac{1}{2}+y}{2}\ne y$.

$x+y-\frac{1}{2}$ goes out of the image for values near the edges.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a monotonic function of two variables?

Comment: Oops. How about now?

Comment: What is a monotonically increasing function of two variables?

Comment: Hm, there doesn't seem to be a consensus on that. For all $x \le x', y \le y'$, $f(x, y) \le f(x', y')$. I think that captures what I'm trying to say (which is that, increasing $x$ or increasing $y$ should never decrease $f(x,y)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it piecewise. For the lower-left quarter:
$$f(x, y) = 2xy$$
For the upper-right quarter:
$$f(x, y) = 1 - 2(1-x)(1-y)$$
For the other two quarters:
$$f(x, y) = x + y - \frac12$$

Comment: That seems to work! How did you figure it out?

Comment: Also, for those interested, here's a quick 'n dirty plot: http://i.imgur.com/5xK8NlF.png

Comment: My first guess, like yours, was $x+y-\frac12$, but that doesn't work. So then I set about fixing the lower left quarter (upper right follows by symmetry). We must have $f(x, 0) = 0$ when $x<\frac12$ by monotonicity, and similarly $f(0, y) = 0$ when $y<\frac12$. So all four edges of the quarter are straight lines. I filled it in by bilinear interpolation.